# Making two player chess app with Django-- need player's board to update when opponent makes a move

Tags: javascript, django

So each player has their own webpage with a Javascript chessboard GUI interface, which they can click to drag pieces. When one player makes a move, I need the other player's chessboard to update with that move. I see how when one player makes a move, I can post the move to the server so that it's available for the other player to request it, but the problem is signaling the other player when a move is made, so they know when to request the new move from the server and use it to update the javascript on their page. What's a good technique to do this?

Comment: Several approaches would be use websockets or WebRTC. The latter is peer to peer communications. Both are realtime updates

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there any chance you know of a good resource that can explain how to use this in more detail?

Comment: Easy to research both technologies on web

Answer (score 1):

Your first option that doesn't require any sophisticated software is polling. Let say, that there is player A and player B playing chess. You can make client's side of both player A and B ask server for update whenever certain period of time elapses. This isn't the most optimalized solution, but it will work.

Something like:

```
function callServerAndWait500Milisecounds(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url: "/your_url_to_server?playerId=" + playerId,
         method: "GET",
         success: function(data){
             //analize data from server and do something with it
         }
      });
   }, 500)
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    //code that fires when client side is loaded
    setTimeout(function(){callServerAndWait500Milisecounds();}, 500);
});
```

If you are using C# MVC for a server side, then you can use SignalR library. Link here: https://www.asp.net/signalr. This library allows both client side to call something on the server and most importantly it allows server to use a function on the client side written in javascript. This library is pretty amazing and it can do a lot of stuff for you like managing groups of users (If player A plays with player B and player C plays with player D then A should be able to communicate with B only and so on).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use Django Channels it a officially Django project at https://github.com/django/channels

It's a WebSockets extension to Django.

Websockets allows you to send a message to the clients without the client polling for it. There is a great examples of this at https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples.